# subclassing celery Task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm writing alot of tasks that are very similar, and want to know how to better subclass the `Task` to reduce boilerplate.  Since a Task is only instatiated once, I you can't put things in `__init__` like I show below, but it should illustrate the point.

what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
class EmailTaskOne(Task):
    def run(self, object_id):
        email_data = EmailData.objects.get(pk=object_id)
        data = self.do_common_stuff(email_data)
        self.do_unique_stuff(data)

class EmailTaskTwo(Task):
    def run(self, object_id):
        email_data = EmailData.objects.get(pk=object_id)
        data = self.do_common_stuff(email_data)
        self.do_unique_stuff2(data)

# lots more tasks like this
```

What I would like to have is:

```
class BaseEmailTask(Task):
     abstract = True
     #...Insert Magic Here...

class EmailTaskOne(BaseEmailTask):
     def run(self, object_id):
         self.do_unique_stuff(self.data)
```

So, since `__init__` is right out, where do I setup the class in the abstract class.  I can define a bunch of functions quite easily if all I want to do is factor out some stuff, but some (lots) of the boilerplate depends on the object_id.

Comment: possible duplicate of [celery task and customize decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393879/celery-task-and-customize-decorator)

Comment: While the solution is applicable - the question asked is different.  As such, I don't think its a duplicate.  If I was trying to increase DRYness of my tasks by using mixins and sublcassing of tasks - I would not be looking for 'customize decorator', but 'subclass' or 'mixin' or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does mine and MauroRocco's answer help you?

see [celery task and customize decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393879/celery-task-and-customize-decorator)

There I succeeded to pass arguments to an extended Task

Comment: Though i don't like accepting link responses, his is a good answer.  in short - override the `__call__` method instead of the `__init__`

Comment: It is a link to my own answer... it's suitable here as well