# catch timeout in celery abstract task class

Tags: python, timeout, celery

I have celery workers and I want them to have a time limit of 60 seconds and cleanup if timeout is reached or task finishes.
I know I should use soft time limits but instead of rewriting try...catch clauses for each task, I want to use an abstract task class that would do that - something in the lines of:

```
class BaseTask(Task):
    abstract = True

    def apply(self, args=None, kwargs=None, link=None, link_error=None, **options):
        try:
            super(self.__class__, self).apply(args, kwargs, link, link_error, **options)
        except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
            print "cleanup time!"
```

This code doesn't work, but is there any way to achieve this?

I have found [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393879/celery-task-and-customize-decorator) that might be similar to what I need:

```
class BaseTask(Task):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print "i'm here"
            return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
        except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
            print "cleanup time!"
```

but the exception isn't raised there ("i'm here" is printed)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I wonder if a custom decorator could achieve the same goal?

Comment: @Erve1879, I haven't found a solution. If you do manage to handle it using a decorator, feel free to answer this question ...

Comment: Any chance you are using windows platform..because SoftTimeLimitExceeded will not work on windows.

Comment: @AnuragUpadhyaya no, RHEL