# Python: How to write to a file and continuously monitor it's file size changes?

Tags: python, celery

I have a python script, which has a method called `produce_output(input)` to generate an output file after running a long running process that's hard to predict how long it will take. Sometimes the process will hang (due to memory or bad input).

In the same script, I want to create a method `has_output_changed()` which will monitor the output file's filesize changes so that if there's no change in file size for more than 5 minutes, we kill the method `produce_output()` and exit the script.

How would I go implementing this?

The `produce_output(input)` is a Celery task that will be run. I want the task to be self aware of the output file size its generating, and terminate itself when it realizes it's not doing any work because a process being used to convert input to output is hanging (ie. memory leak, bad input, low resources).

Comment: This is another approach than what you asked for but might still work for you: have the `produce_output` task write its pid to a file when it starts running and then generate another task periodically in Celery that checks the output file. If it detects a problem, you can `kill -9` it (since it's probably hanging and not responding to another other signals).

Comment: I think yeah that might be a good approach as well. Create a queue to store output file, run a worker that will periodically go through the queue to check if it has been more than 5 minutes, and kill it if the file size has not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only the script is writing to the file, you can simply monitor the time since you last wrote something to the file:

```
import signal, time

# Set time limit to 5 minutes.
time_limit = 300

class TimeoutException(Exception): 
    pass

# Create signal countdown.
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutException("Idle for too long! Exit!")
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
signal.alarm(time_limit) 

# Reset signal countdown every time to write to file.
def print_to_file(msg):
    print(msg) #or other writing method.
    signal.alarm(time_limit)

try:
    # Do your stuff here, for example:
    print_to_file('a')
    time.sleep(time_limit + 1)
except TimeoutException, msg:
    # Nothing happened for 5 minutes!
    print msg
else:
    signal.alarm(0)
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you want it to work for multiple tasks, you should look into [subclassing the Celery Task](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15229240/2801037).