# Celery KeyError when wrapping app.task function with imported decorator; errors only w/ import

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, celeryd

Given the layout:

```
background \
    tasks  \
        __init__.py
        generic.py
        helpers.py
    __init__.py
    _server.py
    config.py
    router.py
    server.py
```

And launching `_server.py` with `celery -A background._server worker`

I'm given a `KeyError: u'generic.adder'` in the Worker when trying to call the `generic.adder` function with a `.delay(..)`

The adder function:

File `generic.py`

```
from background.server import app
from background.tasks.helpers import standardized_task

@standardized_task(app, name='generic.adder')
def adder(x, y):
    return x + y
```

..is wrapped with a function that takes the `app` instance and standardizes the input/output of the Celery Task to JSON object that returns the results and the function. (*included below*) However, the problem is **when this wrapper function is in the same file as generic.adder it works flawlessly -- when it's imported and used as above it throws the key error**.

I'm led to believe that the wrapper is somehow modifying the `name=..` attribute passed to `app.task` with the function name from `helpers.py` which is causing the literal name of `generic.adder` to not be found when accessed from the task.

It's also important to note than if you try and call `adder(..)` from inside `_server.py` (the module run from the celery CLI) it works flawlessly; it's only when called through the distributed interface that the error is thrown; meaning, the import works independent of Celery.

File `helpers.py`

```
__author__ = 'Blake'

import types

JSON_TYPES = [
    dict, list, unicode, str, int, long, float, bool, types.NoneType
]

def standardized_task(app, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped_task(fn):
        def wrapped_fn(*fnargs, **fnkwargs):
            throws = fnkwargs.get('throws', Exception)
            raises = fnkwargs.get('raises', False)

            if not hasattr(throws, '__call__') and not isinstance(throws(), Exception):
                raise ValueError('throws value not of type Exception: %s' % type(throws))

            result, error = None, None

            try:
                result = fn(*fnargs, **fnkwargs)

                if type(result) not in JSON_TYPES:
                    result = unicode(result)

            except throws, e:
                error = e

                if raises:
                    raise
            finally:
                return {
                    'result': result,
                    'error': str(error) if error else None,
                    'meta': {
                        'args': fnargs, 'kwargs': fnkwargs
                    }
                }

        return app.task(wrapped_fn, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped_task
```

File `_server.py`

```
from background.server import app
from background.tasks.generic import *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not to use a decorator, but to extend celery.Task into an abstract class and use, `@app.task(name='...', base=MyNewAbstractTask)`

The following SO post explains it better:

[celery task and customize decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393879/celery-task-and-customize-decorator)

```
import types

JSON_TYPES = [
    dict, list, unicode, str, int, long, float, bool, types.NoneType
]

class StandardizedTask(Task):
    abstract = True

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.inner_run(*args, **kwargs)

    def inner_run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        throws = kwargs.get('throws', Exception)
        raises = kwargs.get('raises', False)

        if not hasattr(throws, '__call__') and not isinstance(throws(), Exception):
            raise ValueError('throws value not of type Exception: %s' % type(throws))

        result, error = None, None

        try:
            result = self.run(*args, **kwargs)

            if type(result) not in JSON_TYPES:
                result = unicode(result)

        except throws, e:
            error = e

            if raises:
                raise
        finally:
            return {
                'result': result,
                'error': str(error) if error else None,
                'meta': {
                    'args': args, 'kwargs': kwargs }}
```