# Python custom decorator not working with Celery tasks

Tags: python, celery, decorator, python-decorators

I'm having a bit of trouble with Python decorators. I've got a scenario set up like so:

```
def decorated(func):
    def call_and_update(*args, **kwargs):
        # do some stuff here
        output = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # do more stuff here
        return output
    return call_and_update

@celery.task
@decorated
def testA():
    return "Test A"

@celery.task
@decorated
def testB():
    return "Test B"
```

For some reason, whichever function I call first seems to be persisted as the `func` in the decorator.

So for instance, if I start up a shell and run:

```
>>> testA()
Test A
>>> testB()
Test A
```

or, if I restart the shell and start with the second test:

```
>>> testB()
Test B
>>>> testA()
Test B
```

I found [this question with a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393879/celery-task-and-customize-decorator?noredirect=1&lq=1), but the few answers revolved around using extended classes for the task methods instead.

If I specifically want to do this via decorators and functions, is there a trick to getting that to work?

Note that *without* the `@celery.task` decorator, the functions work as normal. It's specifically the combination of the two decorators that's causing an issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing this behavior only when you use the celery-task decorator?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga correct. without the celery.task decorator, the functions work as normal.

(I'll make a note of this in the question)

Comment: This is a duplicate. TLDR: use `functools.wraps()` so that the celery task can record the correct function name (otherwise all your tasks are named `call_and_update`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters awesome, thanks! That works as well, and makes things even easier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each task needs to have a unique name [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#names), since it's not provided it is using the name of your wrapper function.

```
@celery.task(name='test-A')
@decorated
def testA():
    return 'test A'

@celery.task(name='test-B')
@decorated
def testB():
    return 'test B'
```

Comment: Yep, that did it! Forgot about this - seems like it naturally defaults to the function name, but when the functions are surrounded by the extra `@decorated` decorator, they were all defaulting to that decorator function name instead. Thanks!

Comment: @CaptainPlanet: You can also just use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) inside of your `decorated` function. This will make your decorated function "look" like the original by updating its name.